# java - problema con clases, me modifica objetos

Tags: java, diseño-de-clases

He creado un par de clases: clase MiCalendar (para manejar clase Calendar a mi gusto), y la clase Periodos.

En la clase periodo tengo un método:

```
 public static periodo diferencia(MiCalendar miCalendarInicio, MiCalendar miCalendarFin) {...}
```

Dentro de ese método, a los objetos que pasan por parámetros se les modifica la fecha y se hace operaciones con ellos y me devuelven un objeto periodo.

Ahora bien, el problema que me encuentro es que cuando en el main llamo al método mediante:
p = periodo.diferencia(i, f);
aparte de devolverme p que es lo que busco, los objetos que paso por parámetros (i y f) sufren las modificaciones que se realizan dentro del método diferencia.Pero esto segundo no lo quiero, pensaba que entraban como parámetros pero no me modificaria los "originales" por asi decirlo.

Comment: Java no entrega valores por referencia :)

Comment: Java es efectivamente `pass-by-value` y no `pass-by-reference` como suele decirse. Pero también es bien cierto que cuando trabajas con objetos, el "valor" que se pasa es el handler del objeto... es decir, pasas el valor... de la referencia. Resumiendo, si quieres evitar modificar un objeto dentro de un método, crea una copia del parámetro y trabaja sobre ella. Nunca modifiques los parámetros directamente y no tendrás ese problema :)

Answer (score 2):

> para manejar clase Calendar a mi gusto

No uses la interfaz Calendar (realmente estás usando GregorianCalendar). Ni la clase `java.util.Date`. Evítalas siempre, porque son parte del API vieja de Java.

Sólo deberías encontrártelas si estás manteniendo código Java realmente antiguo que no se migró correctamente a una versión de Java igual o superior a la 8. Hoy día, cualquier código escrito desde cero en Java 11 o 17 (por hablar sólo de las versiones LTS) debería ignorar completamente el sistema antiguo para tratar fechas.

Desde Java 8 existe el paquete [`java.time.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Una propiedad de todas las clases de este paquete es que sus instancias son inmutables: una vez creas un objeto, puedes usarlo como referencia para crear otro con valores distintos, pero no podrás modificarlo. Por ejemplo:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);
```

De este modo no tienes que preocuparte de si alguien modifica los parámetros porque realmente no puede pasar

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente lo que explica Pablo es correcto. Ahora bien, para entender por qué está sucediendo lo que te está sucediendo, necesitamos entender qué hace en realidad Java cuando pasas un objeto como <s>referencia</s> valor, para ello traigo el siguiente ejemplo absurdo:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Creamos un perrete llamado Perico
        Dog dog = new Dog("Perico");
        // Imprimimos su nombre, efectivamente es Perico, y vemos su referencia...
        System.out.println("Referencia de " + dog.getName() + " antes de empezar: " + dog);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        
        
        // Vamos a probar a cambiarle el nombre primero!
        nameChanger(dog, "Elon Musk");
        // Efectivamente, se habrá cambiado el nombre?? Pero la referencia no habrá cambiado porque no hemos creado un nuevo perro
        System.out.println("Bueno... en teoría nuestro perro ahora se llama diferente, veamos... " + dog.getName() + "! y su referencia es la misma? " + dog);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        
        
        /*
            Ahora llamamos al método dogChanger y le pasamos a nuestro amigo Perico, perdón, Elon
            En teoría debería devolvernos a un perrete nuevo llamado Juanito, cierto?
        */
        dogChanger(dog);
        // Vamos a ver a Juanito! A ver qué tan bonito es...
        System.out.println("Referencia del perrito tras el método: " + dog + " y su nombre es... " + dog.getName());
        // ANDAAAA, pero si este no es Juanito! Sigue siendo nuestro amigo Elon Musk!!
        // Cómo es posible si claramente antes el nombre se cambió, por qué ahora no se ha cambiado el perro?!!
    }
    
    
    
    
    private static void dogChanger(Dog dog) {
        dog = new Dog("Juanito");
        System.out.println("Referencia de " + dog.getName() + " en el método: " + dog);
    }
    
    private static void nameChanger(Dog dog, String newName) {
        System.out.println("En el método cambiamos el nombre del perrete a " + newName);
        dog.setName(newName);
    }
}

// Clase perrete para hacer pruebas, porque el mejor amigo del hombre siempre está ahí para ayudar
class Dog {
    private String name;
    
    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Ejecutando este código obtendremos el siguiente resultado en consola (Las ID de los objetos variarán en cada ejecución, obviamente, pero serán siempre consistentes durante la propia ejecucion)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como se puede ver, las referencias son siempre la misma excepto el objeto nuevo que se ha creado en el método `dogChanger()`, puesto que la referencia que recibimos como parámetro no es una referencia, si no el **VALOR** de una referencia! Es decir, si modificas un atributo del objeto `dog` dentro de un método, estarás modificando el original puesto que es a donde apunta tu objeto ***PERO***! Si modificas la *"referencia"* asignándole un objeto nuevo, como realmente no es una referencia si no el valor de una, lo que estás haciendo es crear un nuevo objeto **TEMPORAL** dentro de tu contexto (el método donde te encuentras) y no estarás afectando a la referencia original, puesto que aquí solo tienes su *valor* y no puedes modificar la referencia externa.

Me explico fatal, así que seguramente esto es más complicado de entender de lo que debería, hagamos un TLDR:
En java los objetos se pasan por ***VALOR DE REFERENCIA***! Si modificas el objeto del parámetro estás modificando el objeto original, si modificas la "referencia" asignándola a un objeto nuevo, estarás creando una nueva referencia y dejando el original **completamente intacto**! Ergo, si necesitas trabajar con tus parámetros, HAZLES UNA COPIA!

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, lo que me extrañaba es que al ser un metodo "externo" en una clase "externa" al main de la clase principal, y pasar esos objetos como parametros los modificase.

SOLUCIONADO mediante:

- Implemento la interfaz Serializable en mi clase MiCalendar
- Creo el método duplica()

MiCalendar duplica() {

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream salida;
    MiCalendar m = new MiCalendar();

    try {
        //Recogemos el objeto y lo serializamos en un objeto de salida
        salida = new ObjectOutputStream(buf);
        salida.writeObject(this);

        //Deserializamos el objeto y lo metemos en un nuevo miCalendar
        ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.toByteArray()));

        m = (MiCalendar) entrada.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: No se puede duplicar el objeto ");
    }
    return m;
}
```

Luego duplico los valores en el método

```
public static periodo diferencia(MiCalendar miCalendarInicio, MiCalendar miCalendarFin) {

    int mesesTrabajados = 0;
    int diasTrabajados = 0;

    //Duplicamos los valores que entran por parametros para que no se modifiquen los orginales
    MiCalendar i = miCalendarInicio.duplica();
    MiCalendar f = miCalendarFin.duplica();
```

Respecto a usar el paquete ** java.time.*. estaba usando una clase que cree ya hace algunos años, asi que me plantearé a actualizarla con ese paquete

un saludo